# How do I remove a dot dollar no name directory

Tags: command-line, quoting, filenames, rm

I have this weird directory in Oracle Linux that I cannot remove, cannot change owner, cannot change group, etc.

It seems to be an environment variable that is empty and is named:  .$EXTEND

## Here's what I've tried:

```
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# ls -al
total 74
drwxrwxrwx  3 psoft psoft 3 May 11 12:42 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 psoft psoft 4 May 11 12:42 ..
drwx------+ 2 root  sys   3 Oct 23  2015 .$EXTEND
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# chown root:root .$EXTEND
chown: changing ownership of `.': Operation not permitted
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# echo $EXTEND

[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# echo .$EXTEND
.
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# chmod 777 .$EXTEND
chmod: changing permissions of `.': Operation not permitted
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# chattr -i .$EXTEND
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on .
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# rm -r .$EXTEND
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# rmdir .$EXTEND
rmdir: failed to remove `.': Invalid argument
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#
```

Comment: Try `'.$EXTEND'`

Comment: As to where those directories are coming from: [they mimic an NTFS feature (`$Extend`), and may be created by Samba](https://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg44155.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can either escape the `$` sign: `rm -r .\$EXTEND`
or
use single quotes: `rm -r '.$EXTEND'`

Answer (score 3):

To differentiate a variable from a string bash uses `$`.

When you do :

```
rm -R .$EXTEND
```

variable $EXTEND is expanded and the result is substituted.

Inorder to remove `.$EXTEND` file you need to tell bash to interpret `$` without its special meaning. You can do it two ways :

```
rm -R .\$EXTEND #\ strips the special meaning of $
```

or

```
rm -R '.$EXTEND'
# Use single quotes. Variable expansion/substitution doesn't happen inside
# single quotes
```

Comment: I tried that syntax. Still no luck.

Comment: [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# rm -R '.$EXTEND'
    rm: descend into directory `.$EXTEND'? y
    rm: remove directory `.$EXTEND'? y
    rm: cannot remove `.$EXTEND': Permission denied
    [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# ls -al
     total 74
     drwxrwxrwx  3 psoft psoft 3 May 11 12:42 .
     drwxrwxrwx  4 psoft psoft 4 May 11 12:42 ..
     drwx------+ 2 root  sys   3 Oct 23  2015 .$EXTEND
     [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

Comment: [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# rm -R '.$EXTEND'
rm: descend into directory `.$EXTEND'? y
rm: remove directory `.$EXTEND'? y
rm: cannot remove `.$EXTEND': Permission denied
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# ls -al
total 74
drwxrwxrwx  3 psoft psoft 3 May 11 12:42 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 psoft psoft 4 May 11 12:42 ..
drwx------+ 2 root  sys   3 Oct 23  2015 .$EXTEND
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

Comment: Try applying the command as root. The previous command failed because if you are not root, you don't have any permissions on .$EXTEND

Comment: if .$EXTEND is a directory, try removing it as root using the command `su -c rm -R '.$EXTEND'`

Comment: I am root. Still doesn't work.

Comment: [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# whoami
    root
    [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# su -c rm -R '.$EXTEND'
    su: invalid option -- 'R'
    Try `su --help' for more information.
    [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

Comment: [root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# rm -R '.$EXTEND'
     rm: descend into directory `.$EXTEND'? y
     rm: remove directory `.$EXTEND'? y
rm: cannot remove `.$EXTEND': Permission denied
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]# ls -al .$EXTEND
total 74
drwxrwxrwx  3 psoft psoft 3 May 11 12:42 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 psoft psoft 4 May 11 12:42 ..
drwx------+ 2 root  sys   3 Oct 23  2015 .$EXTEND
[root@PSFSTSTAPP01 interfaces]#

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the .$EXTEND directory is created on an Oracle ZFS storage system when SMB is enabled.  SMB can be disabled for the pool but the .$EXTEND directory still cannot be removed.